# Is it possible to create Buttons with Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to have a list with Names and next to them a Button, that brings me to that Spreadsheet. But i dont want to create a Button for each one manually.

Otherwise i would create a Sidebar with a Dropdown.. but would prefer the first solution :)

Thank you

Now I just have a single Name with a Single Button

Comment: Do you need that?  On the left of the bottom tab bar there are 4 horizontal lines.  Click on that and it brings up a list of all sheets.  Click on one of them and it will take you to that sheet.

Comment: Yes I do, I have an Product overview site with many informations and would like to make it as easy as possible for others to switch fast to the right sheet... And this way i can save 2 clicks and some Time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Description**

You could simply have a checkbox in the column next to the sheet names.  When the user clicks a checkbox the selected sheet will become active.

Then using a simple onEdit(e) trigger keep an eye on the checkbox column.

Simple, low overhead, no image file needed.

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  try {
    if( ( e.value === undefined ) || ( e.value === "" ) ) return;
    if( e.range.getSheet().getName() === "SheetList" ) {
      if( e.range.getColumn() === 2 ) {
        e.range.setValue(false);
        e.source.setActiveSheet(e.source.getSheetByName(e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue()));
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [onEdit() Simple Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
- [Simple Trigger Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: It works good, Thank you! But how can i add a Button via apps script, every time when i add a new Sheet?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can insert images with Apps Script and use it as buttons. Use [sheet.insertImage()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertimageurl,-column,-row) to insert the image and [assignScript(functionName)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image#assignscriptfunctionname) to assign the function.

See example below:

```
//Function to insert image
function insertImg() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var image = sheet.insertImage("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png", 1, 1); //change the URL to the image you prefer

image.assignScript("sheet"); //assign the function to the image

}

//function that takes you to the sheet you specify
function sheet() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet2'), true); //change Sheet2 to the name of the sheet where you want to go
}
```

Comment: okay, that worked so far, but now i would like to set a custom name and row. So i can use a variable as row number and name. Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: I solved the row Problem but the name problem still exists

Comment: @hepiep What have you tried so far? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. If you can share a copy of the sheet you're working with, it would be helpful.

Comment: I did it with the Chekboxes. The Images didn't worked as i expected because it's not possible to just have one script assinged to multiple images, witch different outcomes, based on the position, where the image is. I learned that Images cant be referenced by its cell its in. :) But thank you for ur help!